# WorkLight: Failed executing POST /applications/upload

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to IBM WorkLight. I am getting an error when I am trying to execute "Build All And Deploy" from the Run menu from eclipse IDE when my Mac connected to Internet (static IPv4). I am using Mac Book Pro with mac os x 10.9. If it is disconnected from the Internet then build will get succeeded. The error message is given below,

> Failed executing POST /applications/upload
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket operation timed out before it could be completed

Please help to resolve this issue. 
Thanks

Comment: What version of Worklight are you using ? Check if your server is running. Could it be that a port conflict is happening when you're connected to the internet ?

Comment: I am using Worklight v6.0.0 Server is running properly. I am getting this error while start deploying the application.

Comment: Are you sure this is happening when you DISconnect your computer from the Internet? Did you try with another Mac/Pc? This is clearly a network issue with your machine.

Comment: @Idan Adar, I am getting this error when connected to internet. I am working with the same at my office; no error. The difference is that I am using static IPv4 at my home and DHCP is enabled at office.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you got more than one IPv4 address for your machine.
can you post here the result of the 'ifconfig' command (while failure occurs)? (run it in terminal).
in such case you will need to tell Eclipse which IP you prefer for your Development Worklight Server or to close extra network interfaces (for example: disable wireless network).

You can affect Eclipse and "hint" what IP should be chosen by using a special environment variable which contains a begining of an IP (or just the whole IP address)
for example: WL_PREFERRED_IP_PREFIX=192.168.4
this will help Eclipse detect your server on 192.168.4.100 (for example).

Comment: Thanks, but how can I tell Eclipse which IP I prefer for my Development Worklight Server ?

Comment: extended my response. look above.